# Creating cases in VBA where String equals different values

Tags: excel, vba

so my last question was too broad so I will attack each problem individually.

I modified a macro to search for the address on google maps, unfortunately the class in which the address is contained is different between "vk_sh vk_bk" and "_erg" (or something like that).

Currently it looks up "vk_sh vk_bk" using this:

```
Dim dd As String
dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("vk_sh vk_bk")(0).innerText
```

If you search a page where the address is not contained in "vk_sh vk_bk" it gets stuck and freezes.

What I'd like to write is a case statement where it goes:

```
if dd = null
Classname = "_erg"
if dd = null (again)
break operation
```

So basically if it can't find the class I need it should change the Classname I'm looking for, and if it can't find it AGAIN then it breaks the operation so it won't freeze.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could write this? Some other questions say to declare strings and have it inside a loop, others day different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dd As String, c

for each c in Array("vk_sh vk_bk", "_erg")
    on error resume next
    dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(c)(0).innerText
    on error goto 0
    If Len(dd) > 0 Then Exit For
Next 

'do something with dd
```